# How to draw a rotated oval in canvas using lineTo() method?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, formula

I want to draw a rotated oval in canvas,I am trying to use lineTo method.

I know using this formula

`xposition = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radiusX;
 yposition = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radiusY;`

can draw an oval, but I dont know how to add some angel as a parameter to make it as rotated, like revolve around x-axis or y-axis or z-axis.

Answer (score 2):

To rotate ellipse about its center, you can use formulas:

```
x = rx * Cos(t) * Cos(fi) - ry * Sin(t) * Sin(fi) + cx
y = rx * Cos(t) * Sin(fi) + ry * Sin(t) * Cos(fi) + cy
```

To rotate about Z-axis (about coordinate origin), use

```
x = (cx + rx * Cos(t)) * Cos(fi) - (cy + ry * Sin(t)) * Sin(fi)
y = (cx + rx * Cos(t)) * Sin(fi) + (cy + ry * Sin(t)) * Cos(fi)
```

To rotate about Y- or X-axes, apply affine transformation of rotation, and ignore Z-coordinate (make projection on OXY plane)

Comment: Can u explain me a bit more about how this formula came out?

Comment: Or is there some links referenced to it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix. Ellipse rotated about center point - rotation+translation

Comment: This one is too complicated, It blew up my mind ,is there any other tutorials for the beginners?

Comment: Sorry,its not very complicated,just too much English words...I prefer some step-by-step tutorials can help me figure out this formulas and its core concept.

Comment: So seek for description of affine transformation that is convenient for you. There are numerous tutorials, courses, books, articles describing this subject in details. In Chinese too, of course